# Multi Table Inheritance Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-table-inheritance

Setting:

A is a model

- With attributes [name, email, actable_id, actable_type]

B and C are sub types of A (as an MTI relation)

[Using this gem to simulate MTI](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as)

A.rb

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  actable
  ...
end
```

B.rb

```
class B < A
  acts_as :A
  ...
end
```

C.rb

```
class C < A
  acts_as :A
  ...
end
```

Problem: Queries on type B return on any table entry with parent A, including C.

```
c = C.create(name, email)

b = B.create(name, email)

B.first # Expected b, actual is c

B.count # Expected 1, actual 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README doesn't tell you to inherit from `A` - it shows the "subclasses" still inheriting directly from `ActiveRecord::Base`